# MySQL simple query to extract substring given 2 delimiters

Tags: mysql, substring, extract

Specifically I need to pick the part of field `label` from table `tmp.label` between delimiters `<!-- rwbl_1 -->` and `<!-- rwbl_2 -->` where `label` contains `<span` in order to be able to update that field for records erroneously formatted with `HTML` tags.

The result amounts to something like `strip_tags`. This is, obviously, only possible due to the presence of the abovementioned (or similar) delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for the abovementioned case to extract a substring given 2 delimiters.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(label, 
            '<!-- rwbl_1 -->', -1), 
        '<!-- rwbl_2 -->', 1) AS cutout 
FROM tmp.label 
WHERE label LIKE '<span%' 
ORDER BY 1 
LIMIT 1;
```

More abstract:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(string_field,        # field name
            'delimiter_1', -1),              # take the right part of original
        '<!-- delimiter_2 -->', 1)           # take the left part of the resulting substring
    AS cutout 
FROM my_table 
WHERE my_condition;
```

And the update now works like this:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET string_field = SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(string_field, 
            'delimiter_1', -1), 
        '<!-- delimiter_2 -->', 1) 
WHERE my_condition;
```